# Getting index based on the first characters from a file in python using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying the get the index of a string in a file based on a regex which is looking for the value '01', but without success, can someone help me?

**My Code**

```
#!/bin/python

import os
import re

finalListFileTxt = 'C:\\USER_ATU\\Processing of TTSCOF00.IMG for file status\\MSS_Sample\\listOfFilesFromTtsFile.txt'
searchedIndexValue = []
with open(finalListFileTxt,"r") as arq:
    for linha in arq.readlines():
        pattern = r'^01$'
        searchedIndexValue = re.findall(pattern,linha)
        print(searchedIndexValue)
```

**Actual Output**

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

**Input**

That's a sample of the content of the file I'm using :

```
022413102101212003
022418102101212003
022423102101212003
022428102101212003
022433102101212003
022438102101212003
022443102101212003
012448102101212003
012453102101212003
021437032812202003
021442032812202003
```

**What I'm looking for**

My idea was to see in my list(searchedIndexValue) the row(not the content of the row) of each row starting with 01 in my file., the values : 8,9

Comment: The regexp `^01$` only matches if the *entire string* consists of the two characters `0` and `1`.  That's not true of any of the lines in the sample content you show, and it isn't even possible for this to be true because the lines will end with a newline character.  Get rid of that `$` in your pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jasonharper, I had tried what you suggested, but the output was the same as I shown here.

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper is right. In addition to what he said, if you want to get the row numbers, you should make something like this:

```
import os
import re

finalListFileTxt = 'teste.txt'
searchedIndexValue = []
with open(finalListFileTxt,"r") as arq:
    for i,linha in enumerate(arq.readlines()):
        pattern = r'^01'
        if re.findall(pattern,linha):
            searchedIndexValue.append(i)
print(searchedIndexValue)
```

enumerate will iterate arq.readlines() and return a pair of linenumber and line.

Comment: hey Vasco Ludovico, really thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the re.finditer method available in re.

```
from re import finditer

with open('Path to file') as file:
   for line in file.readlines():
      occurences = [each.start() for each in finditer('01', line)]
      print(occurences)
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.